# Deleting Opendaylight flow rules for debugging

Tags: opendaylight

I am trying to develop an app using Opendaylight Nitrogen.

For debugging purposes, I want to delete all the flow rules that opendaylight has cached (these get re-installed when the switch reconnects). I want to delete these rules and restart the container to examine behavior. Where does Opendaylight store these (in which file)?

Thanks

Ranga

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete  karaf/target/../journal/ and karaf/target/../snapshots/ when you want to start fresh.

Karf clean deletes the karaf/target/assembly/data directory.

finally, you could also use the REST API to delete the flows on a running
controller. This [documentation](http://docs.opendaylight.org/en/stable-nitrogen/user-guide/openflow-plugin-project-user-guide.html#end-to-end-flows) should help figure that out.

Comment: The data/ directory stores the installed bundle metadata among other things so deleting that won't remove the persisted ODL data. That is stored in the journal/ and snapshots/ as you mentioned.

Comment: @TomPantelis Thanks! Very useful information. Ranga